# C++: Is it possible to use base class reference variables in a derived class?

Tags: c++

I want to use references from the base class without initializing them in the derived class.  Is that possible?  If so, how?

The example code below generates an error, i.e.line 28: error #368: "Base::Base()" provides no initializer for: reference member "Base::BaseVar1"  reference member "Base::BaseVar2"

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base
{
protected:
    int & BaseVar1;
    int & BaseVar2;

public:
    Base() = default;

    Base(int & BaseVar1, int & BaseVar2) : BaseVar1(BaseVar1),BaseVar2(BaseVar2){}

    virtual void vfunction1(void) = 0;
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
public:

    Derived1(int & Derived1Var1): Derived1Var1(Derived1Var1)
    {
    }

    int & Derived1Var1;

    void vfunction1()
    {
        printf("BaseVar1 = \n",BaseVar1);
        printf("BaseVar2 = \n",BaseVar2);
        printf("Derived1Var1 = \n",Derived1Var1);
    }
};

class Derived2: public Base
{
public:

    Derived2(int & Derived2Var1): Derived2Var1(Derived2Var1)
    {
    }

    int & Derived2Var1;

    void vfunction1()
    {
        printf("BaseVar1 = \n",BaseVar1);
        printf("BaseVar2 = \n",BaseVar2);
        printf("Derived2Var1 = \n",Derived2Var1);
    }
};
```

Comment: A reference cannot be left "uninitialized". If you actually need that, use a pointer.

Comment: The whole derived class is a red herring. Your base class alone needs to initialize the member reference variables in the consructor.

Comment: If you don't want to initialize the base object, what `BaseVar1` and `BaseVar2` do you want to bind to?

Comment: With the default constructor, what do you want the references to be bound to?

Comment: I just wanted the classes to use variables in the main program as aliases.  In that way the classes would not have to create any new variables, i.e. use additional memory for new variables.  For the actual program there much more than two variables that are shared by the classes.  Is there way to do it without using the base class?

Comment: But when you call the `Derived1` constructor, what do you want the base class references to be bound to? They need to be bound to something.

Comment: Bathsheba: The references will be bound to something when I create the object.  I just pass the references into the constructor. I have done this previously; however, for that situation, I only had one class.

Comment: Bound to what? That matters to the compiler.

Comment: You are correct.  I guess I should have the derived classes call the base constructor?  Actually, I forgot to include two functions that are used by both base classes.   Those two functions use the base class reference variables.

Comment: As an aside, a reference to an int is likely to be at least as large as the int itself, so it is not saving any memory. Not that saving 4 bytes is all that important.

Comment: You are correct, it is not absolutely necessary . Pointers and non-reference class variables could be used, however, the concept appeals to me.  Also, my example only had a few variables.  There could be more and it could be necessary in an environment that doesn't have a lot of memory.

Comment: remove the Base() constructor and call the other Base constructor from within the initialization list of your derived constructors.

Comment: If you want to reuse memory (e.g. for a small microcontroller), you could either use dynamic memory (new/delete) or use an union of structs. At each time only one struct is active. One reference/pointer to this union is needed only. (or make it a global variable - for this memory limited use case).

Comment: Sebastian:  Do you mean something like this?   
Derived1(int & Derived1Var1,
               int & BaseVar1FromDerived1,
               int & BaseVar2FromDerived1):
         Derived1Var1(Derived1Var1),
         Base::BaseVar1(BaseVar1FromDerived1),
         Base::BaseVar2(BaseVar2FromDerived1)

Comment: Actually `Derived1(int & Derived1Var1, int & BaseVar1FromDerived1, int & BaseVar2FromDerived1): Base(BaseVar1FromDerived1, BaseVar2FromDerived1), Derived1Var1(Derived1Var1)`

Comment: Sebastian: I get an error when I try it that way. error #294: "BaseVar1" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "Derived1"

Comment: Sebastian: I didn't notice your last comment.  I will try it.

Comment: Sebastian: Fantastic...That works and it doesn't require pointers....I wish I could give you more points....

Comment: Sebastian: I like the idea of having only the object creation refer to the variables used, i.e. no main program variables are used in the class.  In that way the code is completely reusable.

Comment: I can put it into an answer later.

Comment: Sebastian:  Ok.  Also, I would like to mention that the classes don't use any more memory than is absolutely necessary to perform its functionality.

Comment: "I just wanted the classes to use variables in the main program as aliases." This does not seem to have a lot of sense from the software engineering perspective.

Answer (score 2):

As some commenters mentioned, references have to be initialized (in the class definition or their member definition or in the constructor).

The default constructor of `Base` does not do that, so it should be removed.

Your derived classes can call the other `Base` constructor from within the initialization list in their constructors.

```
#include <cstdio> // C++ variant of stdio.h, which puts symbols in std
using namespace std; // do not use this in headers (in your production projects)

class Base
{
protected:
    int& BaseVar1;
    int& BaseVar2;

public:
    // Base() = default; // removed

    Base(int& BaseVar1, int& BaseVar2) : BaseVar1(BaseVar1), BaseVar2(BaseVar2) {}

    virtual void vfunction1() = 0;
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
public:

    Derived1(int& BaseVar1FromDerived1, int& BaseVar2FromDerived1, int& Derived1Var1) :
        Base(BaseVar1FromDerived1, BaseVar2FromDerived1),
        Derived1Var1(Derived1Var1)
    {
    }

    int& Derived1Var1;

    void vfunction1() override // signify override
    {
        printf("BaseVar1 = %d\n", BaseVar1); // %d was missing
        printf("BaseVar2 = %d\n", BaseVar2); // %d was missing
        printf("Derived1Var1 = %d\n", Derived1Var1); // %d was missing
    }
};

class Derived2: public Base
{
public:

    Derived2(int& BaseVar1FromDerived2, int& BaseVar2FromDerived2, int& Derived2Var1) :
        Base(BaseVar1FromDerived2, BaseVar2FromDerived2),
        Derived2Var1(Derived2Var1)
    {
    }

    int& Derived2Var1;

    void vfunction1() override // signify override
    {
        printf("BaseVar1 = %d\n", BaseVar1); // %d was missing
        printf("BaseVar2 = %d\n", BaseVar2); // %d was missing
        printf("Derived2Var1 = %d\n", Derived2Var1); // %d was missing
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    Derived2 d2(a, b, c);
    d2.vfunction1();
}
```

Output:

```
BaseVar1 = 1
BaseVar2 = 2
Derived2Var1 = 3
```